# QStringList does not return index by QRegularExpression

Tags: qt, qregularexpression, qstringlist

What am I doing wrong? I want to find an index of a string, which matches given QRegularExpression, in QStringList.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QDebug>

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QStringList list{"bla-bla-bla"};

    qDebug() //Prints "true"
        << QRegularExpression("bla-*").match(list[0]).hasMatch();
    qDebug() //Prints "-1", but I want it was "0" here
        << list.indexOf(QRegularExpression("bla-*"));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to write it like `list.indexOf(QRegularExpression("^bla-*$"))`?

Comment: @vahancho Yep, the same.

Comment: That (sort of?) implies the anchors `^` and `$` are implicit in the second search.  Try changing the regular expression to `"bla-.*"` rather than `"bla-*"`

Comment: @G.M. Thanks. Now it is working, but why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, consider your regular expression...

```
bla-*
```

`QRegularExpression` uses a Perl compatible syntax by default.  That means the `*` character is a quantifier that requires zero or more of the preceding atom.  In this case the atom in question is simply the preceding character: the `-`.  So your regular expression is asking for the text `bla` followed by zero or more `-` characters.

The documentation for [`QStringList::indexOf`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstringlist.html#indexOf-4) states (my emphasis)...

> Returns the index position of the first **exact match** of re in the list,
>   searching forward from index position from. Returns -1 if no item
>   matched

It's slightly confusing but in this instance the phrase `exact match` appears to suggest that implicit begin and end anchors are assumed around the regular expression.  Hence you're actually asking for a match for...

```
^bla-*$
```

That is, the text `bla` at the beginning of the string followed by zero or more `-` characters and then the end of the string.  So no match in this case.  By switching to...

```
bla-.*
```

you ask for a match of `bla-` at the beginning of the string followed by zero or more characters of any value and finally the end of the string.